# New to VMWARE Networking

Tags: vmware

Need help with setting up a home lab.  I have on[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1f73.jpg)e VMWARE ESXI server runnng vmware esxi 5.5.  It has 2 physical NICs.  I have one network that has access to the internet.  I have another network with all my test lab servers.  Can someone give steps on how to setup the second network to gain access to the Internet.  I'm following Windows server base config guide that has you setup a 10.x.x.x.x network.  My home network is a 192.x.x.x.x network.  I have included a picture of what I'm trying to do.  I understand the theory but do not know the steps.

Answer (score 0):

This topic can be incredibly easy or incredibly complex.

As is, the easiest way to put the second network on the internet, you would need to connect your second uplink (NIC) to the second vSwitch (Named: vSwitch1). If those systems have the proper IP addresses and the proper routing config, internet access should work.

Comment: I downloaded pfsense and was wondering how could I configure the pfsense firewall to NAT 10. network to a 192. network so the 10. network could use the 192. to access the network. I figure I would have to put LAN interface on the 10. network and the WAN interface on the 192 netowrk.  But how would I configure the firewall to NAT and then route.